# Arduino Modbus Master code to read data using arduino uno from EB meter

Tags: arduino-uno, modbus

I am using DC energy meter as slave.When I am testing DC energy meter using Modbus tester tool,its showing value from 1 to 24 register.I am using my own atmega328P with on board RS485 as a master device.I have connected A,B from slave to mater board.Now,I want to read slave outputs using my master.For that I have written below mentioned code.when I am serially printing array,its showing 00000000000000000000000000000000769.I am not getting full data on my master.

```
#include <ModbusRtu.h>

// data array for modbus network sharing
uint16_t au16data[64];
uint8_t u8state;

int i;

/**
 *  Modbus object declaration
 *  u8id : node id = 0 for master, = 1..247 for slave
 *  u8serno : serial port (use 0 for Serial)
 *  u8txenpin : 0 for RS-232 and USB-FTDI 
 *               or any pin number > 1 for RS-485
 */
Modbus master(0,0,1); // this is master and RS-232 or USB-FTDI

/**
 * This is an structe which contains a query to an slave device
 */
modbus_t telegram;

unsigned long u32wait;

void setup() {
  master.begin( 9600 ); // baud-rate at 19200
  master.setTimeOut( 2000 ); // if there is no answer in 2000 ms, roll over
  u32wait = millis() + 1000;
  u8state = 0; 
}

void loop() {
  switch( u8state ) {
  case 0: 
    if (millis() > u32wait) u8state++; // wait state
    break;
  case 1: 
    telegram.u8id = 1; // slave address
    telegram.u8fct = 3; // function code (this one is registers read)
    telegram.u16RegAdd = 1; // start address in slave
    telegram.u16CoilsNo = 24; // number of elements (coils or registers) to read
    telegram.au16reg = au16data; // pointer to a memory array in the Arduino

    master.query( telegram ); // send query (only once)
    u8state++;
    break;
  case 2:
    master.poll(); // check incoming messages
    if (master.getState() == COM_IDLE) {
      u8state = 0;
      u32wait = millis() + 100; 
    }
    break;
  }
 //au16data[4] = analogRead( 0 );

 for(i=0;i<=64;i++)
 {
  Serial.print(au16data[i]);
 }
 Serial.println("\n");
 Serial.println("\n");
 delay(1000);
 }
```

Comment: source of the library? shouldn't you print the data only if it is received in case 2?

Comment: source of the library means #include <ModbusRtu.h> right?.So how to receive the polling data on master.

Comment: there is no ModbusRtu library in Library Manager. so from where do you have the library?

Comment: I have downloaded this source code with library from Github .I have mentioned URL on below. https://github.com/smarmengol/Modbus-Master-Slave-for-Arduino/blob/master/examples/advanced_master/advanced_master.ino

Comment: Modbus (0,0,0)  last argument I have changed as 1,because we are usin RS485 and My slave device of A,B is connected on my Master controller of MAX485 and Max is communicated with Atmega328P with the help of software serial.Pin is 8,9

Comment: when I am measuring voltage on my MAX485 IC on pin A ,it giving 1.09V and B its showing 3.89 V

Comment: in simple_master example the author forgot to print the received data, but in the software serial example he prints them in `if (master.getState() == COM_IDLE) {`

Comment: Now I have uploaded software serial master example code on my master controller.I am using external Rs485(D+,D-,Gnd) to TTL board(RX,Tx) for communicating the slave device.I have changed only the software serial pins 8(Rx),9(Tx).I have connected my TTL output on software serial pins (rx-rx,tx-rx viceversa).Even though its printing  '0' on serial terminal.I have tested RS485 to TTL its working fine and when I am testing the salve device in Mtester ,it contains 5453 value on 40001.So how to resolve

Comment: can you check the function code on software serial master example.They have mentioned 4 instead of 3.

Comment: I have changed the function code as 3,software serial pins,no of register need to read .I can able to read all slave response serially on my modbus master controller.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is received when ModbusRtu library object is again in the `IDLE` state after a request was sent. In your code based on the example from the library, the response is ready in state `2` which follows state `1` where the request was sent. If in state `2` when the `master` object state changes to IDLE, you can use the response in array `au16data`.